# Unity3D - Prevent Grid Layout Group rearrange

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i delete an item in grid, grid will rearrange the rest of items, it means they will fill the empty slot of deleted item by others

Is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your GridLayoutGroup contain a set of child container game objects (pseudo speak).

In each container, place the item you desire.

Then, rather than deleting a container, delete the item inside the container instead.
This way, the containers stay in place, and only the items inside get deleted. Therefore, no rearrangement will occur.